# How do I host Node.js and WordPress sites on the same domain name with a different server?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, wordpress, node.js

I would like to host 2 different applications on a different server. For eg `www.example.com` redirected the `NodeJS application - Server A`  & `www.example.com/blog` redirected the `WordPress application - Server B` both applications are hosted in a different server.

is it possible to host Node.js and WordPress sites on the same domain name with a different server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In AWS the best way is probably to use an application load balancer with [path based routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions). This will send traffic to the correct server based on path.

Another way that is less bandwidth efficient but cheaper if bandwidth is ignored is to set up a reverse proxy such as Nginx on one of the servers, redirecting traffic to the other server. All traffic hits the first server, but selected traffic is passed to the second server. In AWS this will probably cost more due to bandwidth charges.